# Bind docker container loopback to the host loopback

Tags: python-3.x, docker, networking, containers

I pull a docker image (will use python 3 as an example)

```
docker pull python:3.6
```

Then I launch a docker container

```
docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:8000:8000 python:3.6 bash
```

(note that here 127.0.0.1 in 127.0.0.1:8000:8000 allows to specify the destination, host IP but not the source)

So if I launch a server inside the container at 0.0.0.0:

```
python -m http.server 8000 --bind 0.0.0.0
```

then I can access the container's server from the host machine without any problem by going to http://127.0.0.1:8000 at the host machine

However if my docker server binds to 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0:

```
python -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1
```

then accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000 from the host does not work.

What's the proper way of binding the container's loopback 127.0.0.1 to the host loopback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What's the proper way of binding the container's loopback 127.0.0.1 to the host loopback?

You can't do that.  The `loopback` interface inside a container means "only this container", just like on the host means "only this host". If a service is binding to `127.0.0.1` then there is no way -- from your host or from another container -- to reach that service.

The only way to do what you want is either:

- Modify the application configuration to listen on all interfaces (or `eth0` specifically), or
- Run a proxy inside your container that binds to all interfaces and forwards connections to the `localhost` address.

Comment: This is not true. Docker containers can be configured to use whatever network namespace you like, including the hosts network namespace - with the caveat that this only works on Linux (since on OSX and Windows, the host is actually running in a VM, it's not your OSX/Windows machine). See https://docs.docker.com/network/host/ for more details. So, if you run "docker run --network=host" on Linux, your docker container will be able to bind to the hosts 127.0.0.1, and connect to it as well.

Comment: I would argue that is different than "binding the container's loopback to the host loopback". Running the container in the host network namespace is exposing *all* host interfaces inside the container, which was not the specific ask in the question. And, as you say, running in the host network namespace is not an option in any case if you're running under MacOS or Windows.

Answer (score 7):

> What's the proper way of binding the container's loopback 127.0.0.1 to the host loopback?

On Linux, this can be done by configuring your Docker container to use the hosts network namespace, ie:

```
docker run --network=host
```

This only works on Linux because on Linux, your machine is the host, and the containers run as containers in your machines OS. On Windows/OSX, the Docker host runs as a virtual machine, with the containers running in the virtual machine, and so they can't share your machines network namespace.

Comment: although it might not answer the question it adds useful background infos

Comment: Notice: The mentioned solution will work, but it mix the network resources of the host with the network resources of the container, which may not be recommended (The main idea of the "container" is to isolate the host and container resources).
Please see @larsks answer about this on this page!

Here is a recommended (Really great!) video to watch about this topic: https://youtu.be/sK5i-N34im8